# VBA changes Interior Color to a random color not specified in code

Tags: excel, colors, vba

I have created a macro to color-coordinate sales transactions based on different criteria. The range is columns F:R, with an unknown number of transactions. I have been using AutoFilter to conditionally format the data.

It first colors the entire row based on transaction Type (sale, void, authorization), and then colors the entire row based on the Response (approved, declined, etc). The last step is to color the actual Card Type (column I) for each of the corresponding transactions. I wanted the AMEX cells to be light teal, and the remaining card type (Discover, MC, and Visa) cells to be pink.

When it colors the AMEX cells teal, it works perfectly. When it moves on to color the remaining card types, which should ALL be pink, I first see a flash of pink, and then they all become DARK TEAL. I have gone through my code repeatedly and cannot figure out why the cells for Discover, MC and Visa are flashing pink for a second, and when the macro has finished running, all the Discover, MC and Visa cells are dark teal. The color code/RGB code for the dark teal color is nowhere in the code... If someone could PLEASE help me, that would be incredible! I am truly stumped!

NOTE: I hope my code isn't too messy. (For example, my named ranges got a little out of hand on this macro.) This is the first time I have posted a VBA question to a forum (or shown anyone my codes, for that matter). If you have any VBA advice, I would love to improve!!

```
Sub PayPalColor()
' PayPalColor Macro
' Color coordinate the PayPal Reports

'Add filters
Range("F1:R1").Select
Selection.AutoFilter

'Reset Used Range
Application.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

Dim LastestRow As Long
LastestRow = Range("K" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

'Sort TYPE alphabetically
Dim rRng As Range
Set rRng = Range("$F$2:$Q$" & LastestRow)
rRng.Sort key1:=Range("G2"), order1:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlNo


With ActiveSheet.Range("$F$2:$Q$" & LastestRow)
' TYPE: AUTHORIZATION
Dim FilteredRange1 As Range
Dim rw1 As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Authorization"

    Set FilteredRange1 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rw1 In FilteredRange1.Rows
        If rw1.Row > FilteredRange1.Rows.Row Then
            'If visible cell, format row here
            With rw1.Interior
                .Pattern = xlSolid
                .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
                .Color = 12566463
                .TintAndShade = 0
                .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

' TYPE: CREDIT
Dim FilteredRange2 As Range
Dim rw2 As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Credit"

    Set FilteredRange2 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rw2 In FilteredRange2.Rows
        If rw2.Row > FilteredRange2.Rows.Row Then
            'If visible cell, format row here
            With rw2.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 16752607
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

' TYPE: DELAYED CAPTURE
Dim FilteredRange3 As Range
Dim rw3 As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Delayed Capture"

    Set FilteredRange3 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rw3 In FilteredRange3.Rows
        If rw3.Row > FilteredRange3.Rows.Row Then
            'If visible cell, format row here
            With rw3.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 16768121
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

' TYPE: VOID
Dim FilteredRange4 As Range
Dim rw4 As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="Void"

    Set FilteredRange4 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rw4 In FilteredRange4.Rows
        If rw4.Row > FilteredRange4.Rows.Row Then
            'If visible cell, format row here
            With rw4.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 15513599
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
            End With
        End If
    Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End With


'Sort RESPONSE alphabetically
Dim rRng2 As Range
Set rRng2 = Range("$F$2:$Q$" & LastestRow)
rRng2.Sort key1:=Range("L2"), order1:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlNo


With ActiveSheet.Range("$F$2:$Q$" & LastestRow)
' RESPONSE: DECLINED
Dim FilteredRange5 As Range
Dim rw5 As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Declined"

    Set FilteredRange5 = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rw5 In FilteredRange5.Rows
        If rw5.Row > FilteredRange5.Rows.Row Then
            'If visible cell, format row here
            With rw5.Interior
  .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 192
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With .Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
        End If
    Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

'RESPONSE: INVALID EXP
Dim FilteredRange5a As Range
Dim rw5a As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Invalid Exp"

    Set FilteredRange5a = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rw5a In FilteredRange5a.Rows
        If rw5a.Row > FilteredRange5a.Rows.Row Then
            'If visible cell, format row here
            With rw5a.Interior
  .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 192
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With .Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
        End If
    Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

' RESPONSE: CREDIT ERROR
Dim FilteredRange5b As Range
Dim rw5b As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Credit Error"

    Set FilteredRange5b = ActiveSheet.AutoFilter.Range.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    For Each rw5b In FilteredRange5b.Rows
        If rw5b.Row > FilteredRange5b.Rows.Row Then
            'If visible cell, format row here
            With rw5b.Interior
  .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .Color = 192
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
With .Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorDark1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
        End If
    Next
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End With

'clear background for card type column
Range("I2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlNone
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With

'Sort CARD TYPE alphabetically
Dim rRng3 As Range
Set rRng3 = Range("$F$2:$Q$" & LastestRow)
rRng3.Sort key1:=Range("I2"), order1:=xlAscending, _
Header:=xlNo


With ActiveSheet.Range("I2:$I$" & LastestRow)
' CARD TYPE: AMEX
Dim FilteredRange6 As Range
Dim rw6 As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="AMEX"

Range("I2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorAccent5
    .TintAndShade = 0.399975585192419
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
    With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

' CARD TYPE: Discover
Dim FilteredRange111 As Range
Dim rw111 As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Discover"

Range("I2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .Color = RGB(255, 51, 204)
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
    With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

' CARD TYPE: MC
Dim FilteredRange121 As Range
Dim rw121 As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="MC"

Range("I2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .Color = RGB(255, 51, 204)
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
    With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

' CARD TYPE: Visa
Dim FilteredRange122 As Range
Dim rw122 As Range
.AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="Visa"

Range("I2").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
With Selection.Interior
    .Pattern = xlSolid
    .Color = RGB(255, 51, 204)
    .TintAndShade = 0
    .PatternTintAndShade = 0
End With
    With Selection.Font
    .ThemeColor = xlThemeColorLight1
    .TintAndShade = 0
End With
        ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

Range("F2").Select

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Is it possible that you have some residual conditional formatting hanging around in your sheet?

Comment: I'm not sure. I haven't physically used the conditional formatting feature, I've only formatted filtered ranges. Do you see anything in my code that could be causing that to happen?

Comment: Why are you setting PatternColorIndex to xlAutomatic.

Answer (score 1):

When I have a problem like this, I often use the "Toggle Breakpoint" option, which in my version of VBA is in the Debug menu.  Maybe add a breakpoint where the pink color assignment takes place, and then use the F8 key until you get to the line of code where the teal/dark teal assignment is taking place.  I wonder if the dark teal could be a range set to teal and then selected/highlighted...

Answer (score 1):

I find using RGB colors to be less problematic, try this:

```
 .Color = RGB(127,187,199)
```

Answer (score 0):

Recommend that you try this without VBA - there are lots of answers in SO about formatting rows based on a condition.  The common formula used looks like this:

```
=INDIRECT("$E"&ROW())=[Value]
```

From there, you can add a other conditional formats for the single column.